# How to write a Power Automate with a list that has several choice columns?

Tags: power-automate

I've been working on a Power Automate to gather changed information from list columns and email them to the owner of the list. So far, my PA works, but for some reason the columns with the "single line of text" display the information correctly while the choice columns look like:

```
[
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
    "Id": 1,
    "Value": "2024"
  }
]
```

I have 6 choice columns this is happening with and my question is how do I make the information display correctly?

[image]

[image]

Looking for a solution based off of the screenshots provided. I've tried adding Initializing variables with no success.

Comment: Can you show us an entire response that you're working with?  Just the value columns kinda doesn't help, we need the entire response to assist with any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your Create HTML table step, try Columns Custom option.
Then for the Value for ChangedTo try:

```
if(empty(item()?['Value']), item(), item()?['Value'])
```

Or...

```
coalesce(item()?['Value'], item())
```